# Java Recursion printing asterisks from one method call

Tags: java, recursion

I have an assignment introducing Recursion in Java and I am running into a roadblock.  The assignment requires a recursion method to output a number of lines of a number of asterisks depending on the integer value passed to it.  For example, if 4 is passed in as variable n, the output would have a first line of one asterisk, next line 2 asterisks, next 3 asterisks, next 4, then 4, 3, 2, & 1 going down.

I have been able to complete the first half of the output (not sure if it is optimal though), but have no clue how to get the method to reverse back down.  This is all to be done in one method call with a variable (n) passed to the method.

Here is the method I have so far:

```
    public static void myMethod(int n)
    {       
    if (n <= 1) {
            System.out.print("*");          
    } else {
        myMethod(n - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }

    System.out.print("\n"); // new line
    }
```

It is called from main with this:

```
    myMethod(n);
```

So what I have is a for loop that will print an asterisk on the same line 'n' times.  After the for loop it proceeds to the next line and cycles, changing n.  But I have no idea how to get it to reverse.

My method prints from the method.  My instructor showed me a sample version passing 2 variables (n) and a null string.

```
    public static String myMethod(int n, String displayStr) {       
        String currentStr = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        currentStr += "*";
        currentStr += "\n";

        if (displayStr == null){
            return myMethod((n - 1), currentStr);   
        } // end base case

        else if (n > 0){
            return myMethod((n - 1), (currentStr + displayStr + currentStr));
        }

        else {
            return displayStr;
        }
    } // end recursion method myMethod
```

His version prints from main using the following code line:

```
    System.out.println(myMethod(n, null));
```

I have tried his version and it prints the triangle on it's side but the largest line only prints once instead of twice.  I have spent all day trying to alter his to add in a duplicate line in the middle and am starting to think it isn't possible.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  I am at a complete standstill with this.

Comment: If you want to place a double n-sized line, you should look at the case where n is max (the first call) -- when `displayStr == null`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method signature to `public static void myMethod(int n, boolean reversed)` where `reversed` is initialized to false but flips to true when you print `n` asterisks.  Inside the method, reverse your logic if `reversed` is true.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to print out the current row, then do the recursive call, then print the row again. That way, you get the stack buildup on the way up, and then again on the way down.

Here is an example that uses 2 parameters, one being the max length and the other being the iterator for the recursion.

```
// bootstrap method to start the recursion
public static void myMethod(int length)
{
    myMethod(length, length);
}

public static void myMethod(int length, int i)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        int rowLength = length - i + 1;

        printRow(rowLength, '*');

        myMethod(length, i - 1);

        printRow(rowLength, '*');
    }
}

public static void printRow(int length, char symbol)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        System.out.print(symbol);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Ok this actually seems to make sense.  My professor likes to teach from powerpoint slides of the textbook, and I learn better from hands on experimentation.  I'll give this a shot too!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Because the output counts *up* (not *down to zero), you must pass in the number of asterisks to print *and* the maximum number, so the terminating condition can be established.

Further, the pseudo code for your method is:

- if n > max return (terminating condition)
- print n asterisks
- recursively call with n + 1
- print n asterisks

A great deal of code simplification can be achieved if you pass in not the current length to print, but the String of asterisks, so your (private) recursive method could be simply:

```
private static void myMethod(int n, String s) {
    if (s.length() < n) return;
    System.out.println(s);
    myMethod(n, s + "*");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

And your public method, which sets up the initial conditions, is then:

```
public static void myMethod(int n) {
    myMethod(n, "*");
}
```

IMHO an elegant implementation with good code density.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you!  My professor asked us to only use one method but when I started asking him questions about his example he couldn't really answer them so I'm not sure if he had his head wrapped completely around the problem either.

Comment: When the terminating condition is arbitrary, you must pass atate through to the next call. Had you wanted to print `4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4` you would only have needed one method, because the terminating condition is known at compile time to be n=0. So your recursive method must have two parameters; there's no getting around it. This pattern of code is quite common - the private code passes whatever extra parameters it needs to and the public API provides a simple API, sets up the initial state and conceals the complexities of the recursive implementation. Basically, your "professor" is wrong.